# Type association from C++ to C#

Tags: c#, c++

What C# type can be associated with this C++ type?:

```
const_cast < unsigned char* > ( reinterpret_cast < const unsigned char* > (variable_name) );
```

At first I guessing it's an *IntPtr* type in C#. 
Am I right?

Comment: It could be an `IntPtr` to a sequence of bytes or a `string`... `char` in c/c++ is used both for bytes and for characters of strings...

Comment: But `IntPtr` is surely legal. It is a C++ pointer, so `IntPtr` is perfectly compatible. The only problem is then what you will do with that `IntPtr` :-)

Comment: You need to get a bit more information than C++ type to do proper interop :) What is the meaning of that pointer and the value it points to? It *looks* like a pointer to a string, which might very well be represented as `string` in C# - but it might just as well be something else. `IntPtr` is just a generic pointer type - it basically tells the .NET runtime not to bother about any "translation", and leave it up to you. Any pointer-sized value can be `IntPtr`.

Comment: Luaan explained perfectly what was inside my head :-) +100%